# Access CGContext outside drawRect to recognize touch event on pie chart and identify touched piece

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, drawrect, cgcontext

I am implementing a custom `UIControl` looking like a pie chart with *n* pieces:
[image: n = 6]

Therefor I subclass `UIControl` and override its `drawRect:` method. In there, I am drawing *n* pieces using `CGContextAddArc`. So, I am going trough a loop depending on how many pieces I have to draw and then set `startAngle` and `endAngle` accordingly.

Now, for the interaction with the control, it's important for me to recognize from a touch event *which* of the pieces has been touched. My approach for that would be to use `CGContextPathContainsPoint`. But I need to call this outside of `drawRect:`, so the `CGContext` is not available.

```
func indexOfTrackForPoint(point: CGPoint) -> Int
{
    // Configure parameters
    let basicTrackAngle = CGFloat(360 / tracks.count)
    let strokeWidth = 60.0
    let radius = CGFloat((CGFloat(self.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(strokeWidth)) / 2) - CGFloat(margin)

    // Initialize the context
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CGFloat(strokeWidth))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)

    for  i in 0...tracks.count-1 {

        // Start and end angles of current track
        var currentTrackStartAngle = CGFloat(i) * basicTrackAngle
        var currentTrackEndAngle = currentTrackStartAngle + basicTrackAngle

        CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, CGFloat(radius), toNormalizedRadian(currentTrackStartAngle), toNormalizedRadian(currentTrackEndAngle), 0)

        if pointOnPath(point, inContext: context){
            println("point found on track: \(i)")
            return i
        }

        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke) // or kCGPathFillStroke to fill and stroke the circle
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to realize this? Is it possible to get the CGContext outside of `drawRect:`?

Answer (score 1):

You can store an array of `UIBezierPath` objects in your `drawRect` implementation. You can then easily hit test them later using the `UIBezierPath` instance method `containsPoint:`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. The issue can be solved by creating my own context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(250.0, 250.0))` having the same size as the initial context of the view. The whole method looks like this now:

```
func indexOfTrackForPoint(point: CGPoint) -> Int
{
    // Configure parameters
    let basicTrackAngle = CGFloat(360 / tracks.count)
    let strokeWidth = 60.0
    let radius = CGFloat((CGFloat(self.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(strokeWidth)) / 2) - CGFloat(margin)

    // Initialize the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(250.0, 250.0)) // THIS LINE SOLVES MY ISSUE
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CGFloat(strokeWidth))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)

    for  i in 0...tracks.count-1 {

        // Start and end angles of current track
        var currentTrackStartAngle = CGFloat(i) * basicTrackAngle
        var currentTrackEndAngle = currentTrackStartAngle + basicTrackAngle

        CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, CGFloat(radius), toNormalizedRadian(currentTrackStartAngle), toNormalizedRadian(currentTrackEndAngle), 0)

        if pointOnPath(point, inContext: context){
            println("point found on track: \(i)")
            return i
        }

        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke)
    }

    println("point not found on arcs")
    return -1
}
```